# Jetbrains MPS Run Invokes CLI Tool

Tags: mps

I've created a DSL in Jetbrains MPS that generates a text config file (using textgen) which is used by another application. I would like to allow users to be able to "Run" each file using the right-click menu from the Logical View. Is this possible with MPS? From the tutorials/documentation, I see how this works if the DSL builds a JAR (as demo'd in the Kajak sample) but I haven't found (or didn't understand) how this could work in other scenarios.

Thanks in advance.